# How to append space at the end of Key and Values in the list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to append space at the end of each key and value in the list of dictionary. I know this sounds odd but i have a requirement which need this kind of list of dictionaries. Any suggestions!

Example:

```
# Original List of dictionary
my_list = [{'Table': 'A', 'Column': 'C1', 'DataType': 'int'},
       {'Table': 'A', 'Column': 'C2', 'DataType': 'varchar'},
       {'Table': 'B', 'Column': 'C3', 'DataType': 'int'}
       ]
# Have another list of dictionary which specifies the space needs to add at the end of each key and value pair.
position_list = [{'Table': 10}, {'Column': 15}, {'DataType': 10}]
```

So here i need to append 10 space at the end of key and its value.

```
# Expected out put (Spaces may not be exact as shown below but expecting something like.)
list = [{'Table             ': 'A           ', 'Column               ': 'C1                  ', 'DataType                ': 'int             '},
       {'Table             ': 'A           ', 'Column               ': 'C2                  ', 'DataType                ': 'varchar         '},
       {'Table             ': 'B           ', 'Column               ': 'C3                   ', 'DataType                ': 'int            '}
       ]
```

also my list of dict always varies so my_list and position_list will change every time, so no way i can hard code the keys and the space specified.

Comment: Idea: Iterate and Copy my_list elements to another intermediate list changing both key, value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [{'Table': 'A', 'Column': 'C1', 'DataType': 'int'},
           {'Table': 'A', 'Column': 'C2', 'DataType': 'varchar'},
           {'Table': 'B', 'Column': 'C3', 'DataType': 'int'}]

position_list = [{'Table': 10}, {'Column': 15}, {'DataType': 10}]
positions = defaultdict(lambda : 10)
for d in position_list:
    positions.update(d)

print [{k + ' ' * positions[k] : v + ' ' * positions[v] for k,v in d.items()} for d in my_list]
```

This outputs:

```
[{'DataType          ': 'int          ', 'Table          ': 'A          ', 'Column               ': 'C1          '}, {'DataType          ': 'varchar          ', 'Table          ': 'A          ', 'Column               ': 'C2          '}, {'DataType          ': 'int          ', 'Table          ': 'B          ', 'Column               ': 'C3          '}]
```

EDIT:

If you want your keys and your values to have the same spacing, simply use this (`positions[k]` instead of `postions[v]`).

```
print [{k + ' ' * positions[k] : v + ' ' * positions[k] for k,v in d.items()} for d in my_list]
```

Comment: But looks like the key and value is not in sync with the space. key and its value need to have same space at the end defined in the position_list. @DevShark

Comment: I didn't realize that's what you wanted. See my edit to do this.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. By the way, I am not sure what you're doing, but it does not feel very clean. Data and formatting should not be mixed together. Looks like you have to deal with unpleasant requirements!

Comment: I am doing so because I need to write the new list of dict into a file with those spaces, so that some other process will read the file based on the position for each header defined. @DevShark

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know why you need this. It violates [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)*

Anyway one way to do this is using using the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to format your key/value pairs. But first you will need to convert your "position_list" to a regular `dict`. Then iterate over the list of your `dict`s and format the items.

```
>>> my_list = [{'Column': 'C1', 'DataType': 'int', 'Table': 'A'},
...  {'Column': 'C2', 'DataType': 'varchar', 'Table': 'A'},
...  {'Column': 'C3', 'DataType': 'int', 'Table': 'B'}]
>>> position_list = [{'Table': 10}, {'Column': 15}, {'DataType': 10}]
>>> d = {k:v for item in position_list for k, v in item.items()}
>>> res = []
>>> for element in my_list:
...     item = {}
...     for key, value in element.items():
...         width = len(key) + d[key]
...         item["{:<{width}}".format(key, width=width)] = "{:<{width}}".format(value, width=width)
...     res.append(item)
... 
>>> import pprint # Just to pretty print res nothing special.
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
[{'Column               ': 'C1                   ',
  'DataType          ': 'int               ',
  'Table          ': 'A              '},
 {'Column               ': 'C2                   ',
  'DataType          ': 'varchar           ',
  'Table          ': 'A              '},
 {'Column               ': 'C3                   ',
  'DataType          ': 'int               ',
  'Table          ': 'B              '}]
```

Comment: I understand, my approach for one of my requirement is not the clean one. But got a very odd requirement and i thought this could be one way to resolve this! @user3100115